# Button doesn't seem to take the jquery ui button effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am try to apply the jquery ui effect on a button, this is my head

```
 <head>
    <title>Bootstrap V3 template</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">


    <link href="css/travelbuddy.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
      <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->

    <script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js"></script>


    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-selectify.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/selectify.css" />
    <script src="js/myfunctions.js"></script>



  </head>
```

Everything seems to be loaded since there is no error in the Chrome console and I can see the files in the resources of the inspector.

Here is the part where I have my button:

```
<div class="container" >
      <div class="row-fluid" >
          <div class="span6" id="MyProfile">
          <h1>Your profile</h1>
            <form action="" method="post" id="registerform">
              <p>
                <label for="firstname">Firstname</label>
                <input class="inputfields" type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" />
              </p>
               <p>
                <label for="lastname">Lastname</label>
                <input class="inputfields" type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" />
              </p>
               <p>
                <label for="email">Email</label>
                <input class="inputfields" type="email" name="email" id="email" />
              </p>
               <p>
                <label for="phonenumber">Telephone number</label>
                <input class="inputfields" type="tel" name="phonenumber" id="phonenumber" />
              </p>
               <p>
                <label for="birthday">Birthday</label>
                <input class="inputfields" type="datetime" name="birthday" id="birthday" />
              </p>
              <p>
              <label for="selectgenre">Genre</label>
              <select id="selectgenre">
                <option value="male">Male</option>
                <option value="female">Female</option>
              </select>
              </p>
              <p>
                <label for="cities">Where do you live?</label>
                <input  class="inputfields" type="text" name="cities" id="cities" />
              </p>
              <input id="saveprofile" type="submit" value="A submit button">
              </form>
              </div>
              <div class="span2 offset1" id="MyPhoto">
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

And in my function I simple have:

```
$( "#saveprofile" ).button();
```

I also tried:

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
   $( "#saveprofile" ).button();
});
```

but didnt work. Any idea what I am missing?

Comment: Are you calling the jQuery function inside document.ready()? If not, it may be calling the function prior to the button being displayed on the DOM.

Comment: I am calling it using `onload` on the body tag.

Comment: any luck changing the `input` tag to a `button` tag?

Comment: @whodeee yes I tried it but no luck. I suppose the problem is that Brendan mention, I am trying to solve it.

Comment: please put it just before the `</body>` closing tag, should work
`<script>
$( "#saveprofile" ).button();
</script>`

Comment: @aks007 actually it didn't

Comment: @BrendanScarvell I tried but still doesnt work, check my edit.

Comment: @Avraam I will suggest for live example under `http://jsfiddle.net/` for better understanding.

Comment: I don't imagine it has any bearing on the problem but your #saveprofile `input` tag is not closed.